# PyQt New Window Instance showing and closing immediately

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt4, pyqt5

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

    def new(self):
        newFile = Window()
        newFile.show()
```

I didn't show the full code becuase it's too long.I have tested that is the window

created or not by using print and the window is actually created but it closes 
**immediately**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, `newFile` only exists within the scope of the `new()` function. You need to store the instance that you create or it will get garbage collected.

```
self.newFile = Window()
self.newFile.show()
```

Comment: I will try this wait